# Setting sitecore's item properties from a parent on creation/save

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have the following question regarding Sitecore item creation:
Given the following content tree:

```
a.Value 
--b(folder)
```

If I want to assign the `a.Value` to a child of `b`, so that the content tree will look like this:

```
a.Value 
--b(folder) 
 --c.Value
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do this two ways (or even many more):

1. Create a command template with custom code to duplicate the `a` item below its `b` child folder. Section 4.1 of the [Data Definition Cookbook (PDF link)](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/datadefinitioncookbook-a4.pdf) will explain how to create them.
2. Create an event handler for item creation with custom code to duplicate the `a` item below its `b` child folder when `a` is created. You can likely do this on the `item:saved` or `item:created` event. Refer to the [Using Events](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Using%20Events.aspx) page on the SDN for help.